# Поддерживают ли стандартные средства Qt парсинг HTML XPath?

Tags: html, c++, xml, qt, xpath

Суть вопроса можно понять по заголовку вопроса.

Я так понимаю, что `XQuery` поддерживает только парсинг `XML`?

Comment: XPath это технология для XML, а не HTML. Поэтому суть вопроса мне не ясна. Корректный HTML, можно скормить XPath.

Comment: @ixSci, какими средствами?

Comment: используя [QXmlQuery](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qxmlquery.html)